# 複数ファイルから数値を抽出して計算したい

Tags: c, unix

下記のファイル(1つ目のファイル)の1列目に対して別ファイルの値(2つ目のファイルのFermi energy is     6.9266 evの6.9266)で引きたいのですがどうすればよろしいでしょうか。また、計算結果後の数値を１つ目のファイルに組み込みたいです。目的として1つ目のファイルの1列目(6.9266で引いた値)と3列目を用いたグラフを作成したいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

＊1つ目のファイル

```
＃　E (eV)   dos(E)     Int dos(E) EFermi =    6.927 eV
-16.844  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
-16.834  0.7721E+00  0.7376E-02
-16.824  0.8280E+00  0.1538E-01
-16.814  0.8844E+00  0.2394E-01
-16.804  0.9412E+00  0.3306E-01
-16.794  0.9986E+00  0.4276E-01
・
・(略)
・
```

＊2つ目のファイル

```
・
・(略)
・
-16.4186 -16.0081 -15.3148 -14.8071 -14.7569 -14.7353  -5.9508  -4.6087
-3.7741  -2.8666  -2.5273  -2.3434  -0.6640  -0.5462   0.0910   0.1959
0.4589   1.0149   1.1588   1.3790   1.5706   1.7128   2.0235   2.4136
10.9011  11.9243  12.0415  12.5293  12.6880

the Fermi energy is     6.9266 ev
(compare with:     2.4949 eV, computed in scf)

Writing output data file out_qa/qa.save/

init_run     :      2.09s CPU      1.48s WALL (       1 calls)
electrons    :    138.30s CPU     97.36s WALL (       1 calls)
・
・(略)
```

Comment: やりたい事を細かい手順に分解していき、どの工程が分からないのか質問を絞りこんだ方が回答もつきやすくなると思います。例えば2つ目のファイルは無視して 6.9266 の値を固定で1つ目のファイルから抽出することはできますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。抽出はできるのですが１つ目のファイルの１列目を6.9266(値は変動する)で引く方法がわからないです...

Comment: この処理は C で行わなければならないのでしょうか？ `unix` のタグが付いていまが、例えば awk + gnuplot で処理するととても簡便にできます(他にも python + matplotlib などでも良いかと思います)。

Comment: @リヨチ StackOverFlow は質問者個人をお助けすることが究極の目的ではなくて、質問者の「質問」を一般化してナレッジベース的に役立てようという趣旨があります。この場合、例えば、まずは、2 つ目のファイルの「Fermi energy is X.XXXX ev」の数値を抽出する方法に焦点を絞った質問とした方がいいと思います。

Comment: awk+gnuplotでの処理を試してみます。貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。

Comment: @hete ご指摘ありがとうございます。StackOverFlowの使い方について今一度考え直します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 下記のファイル(1つ目のファイル)の1列目に対して別ファイルの値(2つ目のファイルのFermi energy is 6.9266 evの6.9266)で引きたいのですがどうすればよろしいでしょうか。
> また、計算結果後の数値を１つ目のファイルに組み込みたいです。目的として1つ目のファイルの1列目(6.9266で引いた値)と3列目を用いたグラフを作成したいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

シェルスクリプトでのコード例です。
1つめのファイルをf1.txt、2つ目のファイルをf2.txtとします。

2つめのファイルのFermi energy is 6.9266 evの6.9266を抽出するにはsedを使っています。
※条件に合致する行がひとつしかない前提です。複数ある場合はもう一工夫必要です。
抜き出した数値は変数v1に格納しています。

1つめのファイルの処理にはawkを使っています。
ファイルから1行ずつ読み込んで、＃を含まない行に対して、第1から第3列と「第2列-v1」を第4列として出力しています。

```
v1=$(cat f2.txt | sed -n 's/^the Fermi energy is  *\([0-9\.][0-9\.]*\) ev.*/\1/p')
awk '
BEGIN {
    v = '${v1}'
}
!/＃/{
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $2 - v)
}
' f1.txt
```

C言語で実装する場合も考え方は利用できると思います。

---

【追記】
実行例です。
q.shにコードを書いて、bashで実行しています。

```
bash q.sh
```

1つ目のファイル(f1.txt)

```
＃　E (eV)   dos(E)     Int dos(E) EFermi =    6.927 eV
-16.844  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
-16.834  0.7721E+00  0.7376E-02
-16.824  0.8280E+00  0.1538E-01
-16.814  0.8844E+00  0.2394E-01
-16.804  0.9412E+00  0.3306E-01
-16.794  0.9986E+00  0.4276E-01
```

2つ目のファイル(f2.txt)

```
-16.4186 -16.0081 -15.3148 -14.8071 -14.7569 -14.7353  -5.9508  -4.6087
-3.7741  -2.8666  -2.5273  -2.3434  -0.6640  -0.5462   0.0910   0.1959
0.4589   1.0149   1.1588   1.3790   1.5706   1.7128   2.0235   2.4136
10.9011  11.9243  12.0415  12.5293  12.6880

the Fermi energy is     6.9266 ev
(compare with:     2.4949 eV, computed in scf)

Writing output data file out_qa/qa.save/

init_run     :      2.09s CPU      1.48s WALL (       1 calls)
electrons    :    138.30s CPU     97.36s WALL (       1 calls)
```

出力結果

```
-16.844 0.0000E+00 0.0000E+00 -6.9266
-16.834 0.7721E+00 0.7376E-02 -6.1545
-16.824 0.8280E+00 0.1538E-01 -6.0986
-16.814 0.8844E+00 0.2394E-01 -6.0422
-16.804 0.9412E+00 0.3306E-01 -5.9854
-16.794 0.9986E+00 0.4276E-01 -5.928
```

GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。上記のコードで実行したところ、4列目(2列-v1)での計算がうまくいかないみたいです(2列目がそのまま出力される)。試行錯誤して原因の特定に努めます。

Comment: vが0になっているように思えます。awkの実行直前でecho ${v1}を実行して値を確認してみるのがいいと思います。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございました。無事実行することができました。原因はf2.txtの元ファイルにおいて「the Fermi energy is     6.9266 ev」の前にスペースがある為でした